# checking multiple conditions in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an condition in which i have to test two things below are the conditions

1) to test abc/@abcflowId = abc/@setId

2) and if above condition is true then check RegId value it should not be 'IR_1' and 'IR_2'

so if both the conditions are true then show the text Delivery all these otherwise do nothing i have come up with the below approach but it is not working please advise how to correct this

```
<xsl:if test="$PASS='true'">
            <xsl:if test="abc/@abcflowId = abc/@setId and abc/RegId != 'IR_1' and abc/RegId != 'IR_2' ">
                <PassThru/>
                <xsl:text>Delivery all these</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: what is your problem with this XSLT - it doesn't look too bad. Please show the input XML as well.

Comment: "*it is not working*" is not a good description; post some code that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you have provided you can try this

```
<xsl:if test="$PASS='true'">
            <xsl:if test="abc/@abcflowId = abc/@setId and (abc/RegId != 'IR_1' and abc/RegId != 'IR_2') ">
                <PassThru/>
                <xsl:text>Delivery all these</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same test as the one in the question.